# Upgraded IIS. Now :80 is appended to all urls sent to isapi rewriter

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We recently upgraded from IIS 5.0 and windows 2000 to IIS 7 and windows 2008.  For handling url rewrites, we use Helicon Isapi Rewrite 3.

With the new configuration, our rewrite rules are failing because IIS is appending a :80 to our links.
For instance, on the old site.
/media/hr/pdf/application.pdf would redirect to our static server just fine.

On the new site, /media/hr/pdf/application.pdf  generates a 404 saying that 
:80/media/hr/pdf/application.pdf   could not be found.

here is the rule.
RewriteRule (^|^/)(media/.*) http://static.mysite.com/global/images/$2  [NC,L,O]

Does anyone know a way to stop the :80 from being added?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, but....

you can use the built-in IIS7 rewriting module from Microsoft.  It's free.  It's more commonly used that Helicon's.  There's a capability for slurping in rules that are compatible with Apache mod_rewrite, which I think is the same as the syntax for Helicon.  Consider it. Find it at http://iis.net

Also - there's a free, open source rewriter that works with IIS7, called IIRF.  It won't add :80 to your URLs. Find it at http://iirf.codeplex.com